# Text-align property confusion

Tags: html, css

I'm learning my way through bootstrap & CSS and sometimes I notice that `text-align` doesn't always work the same, so for my own understanding, could someone explain the phenomenon that I'm experiencing with `text-align: center;`?

**Reproduction of Problem**:

I have a button which consists of a container `DIV` which is positioned absolute, and within that `DIV` is an `a` tag, and within that is a `span` tag which wraps the link text.

My own understanding of CSS thus far led me to believe that if I applied `text-align:center` to the `a` tag, the text should have centered itself within the `DIV`, but it wasn't until I applied the center rule to the div itself, that the text within it aligned itself.  Am I missing something here?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="link-wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <span>Text</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.link-wrapper{
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #c74e3e;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    /* line-height: 35px; */
    padding-top: 6px;
}

.link-wrapper a{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.link-wrapper a span{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text-align: center;` is applied to the elements within the element you apply it to.

***As far as why it didn't work on the anchor:*** An anchor element's (`<a>`) display value by default is `inline`. Which basically means it will only be as large as it's content. So technically speaking the text was being centered when you applied it to the anchor element but wasn't obvious because the anchor's width was the same as the text.

If you change the display value of the anchor and give it a width you'll see what I'm saying:

```html
<div class="link-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <span>Text</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

```css
.link-wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #c74e3e;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    /* line-height: 35px; */
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.link-wrapper a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px dashed white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mnekkn03/.

If you were to apply `display: block;` to the anchor element it would fill up the `.link_wrapper` DIV and `text-align: center` would work on the anchor element.

```html
<div class="link-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <span>Text</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

```css
.link-wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #c74e3e;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    /* line-height: 35px; */
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.link-wrapper a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px dashed white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uk91ybca/.

Personally, unless there is other reason to do so, I would apply `text-align: center` to the `.link_wrapper` DIV.

```html
<div class="link-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <span>Text</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

```css
.link-wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #c74e3e;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    /* line-height: 35px; */
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: center;
}
.link-wrapper a {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/opamhc3y/

Comment: Ah, great example!  I completely forgot that an anchor is only as big as its' content.  In your example - I changed the anchor tag to be `display:block`; and then `text-align:center`; worked as normal.  I will accept your answer in 2 minutes when it will allow me to.

Answer (score 0):

To center an `inline-block` or `inline` level, you have to apply the`text-align: center;` to the parent `block` level like this

```css
.link-wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #c74e3e;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  /* line-height: 35px; */
  padding-top: 6px;
  text-align: center;

}

.link-wrapper a{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="link-wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <span>Text</span>
  </a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `a` and `span` are inline elements there are no use of adding `text-align` property to them, their width is equal their content width so there is no space where content can be centered.

You can apply `text-align: center;` to `.link-wrapper`, `.link-wrapper` is a block element and has its own width.

Or you can change display type for `a` or `span` to `display:block;` in order to make them block elements with their own width.

Answer (score 0):

Move `text-align` to the `.link-wrapper` rule. The reason this works is because the link-wrapper element is a block (since it's a div). Inline elements such as the `<a>` or `<span>` tags always size to their contents, so centering within that context doesn't really make sense. Of course, you can always change this by using `display: block` in the CSS.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp), you can see a couple of good, visual examples.

Answer (score 0):

think of the `text-align` as a relationship between 2 elements - one outer and one inner. the outer one is the thing that is the width you're working with and the inner one is the thing you want to center inside the outer element.

what you tried to do by putting `text-align` style in `<a>` is to center the text in the `<a>` itself. however, the `<a>` element's width is normally defined by the length of the text within it, so technically, its working as it should - centering the text of the `<a>` in the center of the `<a>`. the width of a just happens to be the same size as the width of the text

however in this case, you want to center the link text within the `div .link-wrapper` because you want the text (and by default the link element) to be in the center of the `div`. so you put `text-align: center` on the `div` element so that everything inside the `div` will be centered horizontally.

in the case that you want to center the text within the `<a>` itself, just stick a width on the `<a>` (although i dont really find that many useful cases for this particular situation, unless you're making the anchor look like a button with a fixed width)

Answer (score 0):

For `text-align: center;`,
Summary of Rules:

1. apply to children
2. centers children horizontally
3. only applies to inline and inline block elements

Applying `text-align: center;` to `a` tag won't have any effect. Because `a` tag is an inline element. Inline elements, contrary to block elements don't expand horizontally as much as they can. Instead, they try to shirnk and fit around content inside them. So as small as possible/ fit to content.

Now as you can see even if text inside a element is 'centered' it wont really change anything unless you do:

```
a.your_ele {
   display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
}
```